# StaXNetwork - UWP Stack Exchange client

Tags: app, windows

## About

StaXNetwork is a UWP app for browsing, asking, searching and answering questions on the whole Stack Exchange network.

### Features

- Browse through and search for questions on all Stack Exchange communities.
- Ask, answer and comment questions
- Vote for posts
- Get detailed information about the different sites and their users
- Log in to your Stack Exchange account

### Download

StaXNetwork is available on the Windows Store.

[image: Get it from Microsoft]
<sub>(source: [windowsphone.com](https://assets.windowsphone.com/85864462-9c82-451e-9355-a3d5f874397a/English_get-it-from-MS_InvariantCulture_Default.png))</sub>

## Screenshots

(Click images for larger views.)

### Desktop:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

### Mobile:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]